# Need to disable/trap the screen capture button on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

The Samsumg Galaxy Tab 10.1 has an additional button on the task bar to capture screen shots. Is there any event triggered to trap or stop this button in an application? I'm using the version 2.2 SDK. The tablet runs 3.0.

This webpage shows the additional button http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/10.1/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory it should respect [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE), and not include your window in the screen shot if it has set this flag.